# Constructor objects, methods not recognized

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I'm building a JavaFX form. I have written an InputForm class that is intended to represent the first page of the form; ideally when the InputForm() constructor is called in the Application subclass, the form's Scene, GridPane object, and field and label nodes are initialized.  Code snippet from CallRecord (Application subclass):

```
InputForm inputForm = new InputForm();

inputForm.input_1_labelString = "Name: ";
inputForm.input_1_errorString = "Please provide a name";
inputForm.input_2_labelString = "Company: ";
inputForm.input_2_errorString = "Please provide a company";
inputForm.input_3_labelString = "Issue: ";
inputForm.input_3_errorString = "Please provide a brief description of issue";
```

The problem I'm running into is the constructor doesn't seem to be called when the inputForm instance of my class is constructed above. What's happening is the window appears blank when the application is run. Below is the code block for the InputForm class. It seems the code for the Label and Text objects is not recognized in the application thread. I'm fairly new to Java, so it could be that I'm totally misunderstanding the purpose of the class constructor. I appreciate any insight.

```
   public class InputForm {

        //CLASS CONSTRUCTS SCENE AND GRIDPANE WITH CHILDREN NODES
        //QUESTION LABEL STRINGS TO BE SET IN APPLICATION CLASS
        GridPane inputGrid = new GridPane();
        Scene inputScreen = new Scene(inputGrid, 500, 300);

        //text strings for field labels, error messages
        String input_1_labelString;
        String input_1_errorString;
        String input_2_labelString;
        String input_2_errorString;
        String input_3_labelString;
        String input_3_errorString;

        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        HBox hbSubmit= new HBox(10);

        public void InputForm() {

        //question label and field nodes
        TextField input_1 = new TextField();
        Label input_1_label = new Label(input_1_labelString);
        Text input_1_error = new Text(input_1_labelString);

        TextField input_2 = new TextField();
        Label input_2_label = new Label(input_2_labelString);
        Text input_2_error = new Text(input_2_labelString);

        TextArea input_3 = new TextArea();
        Label input_3_label = new Label(input_3_labelString);
        Text input_3_error = new Text(input_3_labelString);

        //adding nodes to inputGrid
        inputGrid.addRow(1, input_1_label, input_1);
        inputGrid.addRow(2, input_2_label, input_2);
        inputGrid.addRow(3, input_3_label, input_3);
        inputGrid.addRow(4, hbSubmit);
        hbSubmit.getChildren().add(submit);
        hbSubmit.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove the `void` on your method. Right now it's just a method with the same name as your class. So `public void InputForm()` should be changed to `public InputForm()`.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor has a void in front of the name and that is not constructor that is method. That is wrong because constructor doesn't have return type of any kind. In this case you have a method with name "InputForm" and your class will call default constructor and it is hidden and  empty.. Remove word void in front of constructor name, your constructor should be like this 
public InputForm()
{
   some code here...
}

notice, there is no return type in front of constructor name!!